# How to remove title "confirm" from confirm box in IOS app using cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to remove "confirm" title from confirm box,
I am getting page name in confirm dialogue box, that is looking very awkward.

Please help me to remove title from confirm dialogue box.

Comment: Are you using `notification.confirm`?

Comment: nothing happens, i had already used

Comment: I am also using this plugin and want to hide the title. But according to the docs the parameter is optional and defaults to 'Confirm' so I don't think that is possible [https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#navigatornotificationconfirm](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#navigatornotificationconfirm)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `window.confirm()` as this uses the built-in confirm dialog of the WebView which does not look very elegant and the title is not customisable.

Instead, install [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) into your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs --save
```

Then you can call its [confirm dialog API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs#navigatornotificationconfirm) with a custom title:

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Your message',        // message
     onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Custom title',        // title
    ['Button1','Button2']  // button labels
);
```